# duplicate behavior in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I was just playing around with hash tables and I did this:

```
$C = @{color = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@(@{y = 'yellow'},@{y = 'blue'})}
```

and I ended up with finding I can do:
`($C.color.y).Get(1)` or `($C.color.y).Item(1)` and it does exactly the same thing.

I also found even though the autocomplete doesn't show you can do this you can:

```
($C.color.y).Get(0).Contains('yellow')
($C.color.y).Get(1).Contains('blue')
```

The `Get` and `Item` methods appear to be interchangeable what is the difference between them?
I did check the hash codes they are the same.

`($C.color.y).Get(1).GetHashCode()` or `($C.color.y).Item(1).GetHashCode()`

Comment: What is `$C.color`?

Comment: it's a hash table I made up. `$C` could be anything really. I just couldn't think of anything else to call it.

Comment: Are you sure? `[hashtable]` doesn't have a `Get` member, and has no overload for `Add()` taking a single argument. Can you show how you defined and populated `$C`?

Comment: that should fix it.

Comment: it's a hashtable of a list of hashtables

Comment: Ahh, I see. This might be slightly confusing, but `$C.color` is not a hashtable - it's an `ArrayList` (containing hashtables). When you nest it in `()`, PowerShell interprets it as a _pipeline statement_, at which point it unravels the list - and the resulting value of `($C.color)` is therefore `[object[]]`. `[object[]]` (and all other array types) have a `Get()` method because someone thought it was a good idea - and also implement the `Item()` parameterized property to satisfy the [`IList` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist)

Comment: I guess that makes enough sense.

Comment: can you give me where I can find more information about `[object[]]` is that from C#?